# How this works "elements.map(({ length :lengthFooBArX }) => lengthFooBArX);"

Tags: javascript

I was reading about arrow functions here(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions) But couldn't understand how do these two parts work?

```
var elements = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

elements.map(({ length :lengthFooBArX }) => lengthFooBArX); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

elements.map(({ length }) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; `length` is a property of a string, and you're using destructuring to access that property of whatever is passed into `map`, in this case your array of strings.

Comment: @DaveNewton: What does this part do?  `{ length :lengthFooBArX }`

Comment: Do you understand *parameter destructuring* in general?

Comment: @user145959 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Comment: @deceze That's... self-answering ;)

Comment: @Dave Since OP is asking specifically about `lengthFooBArX`, it could just be they don't get the aliasing part…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start, we create an array of string items.
After it, we call function `map()`, passing to it function same as

```
function({ length }){
    return length // We get as length property length of the input object
}
```

Second code snippet:

```
function({ length: lengthFooBArX }){
    return lengthFooBArX // We get as lengthFooBArX property length of the input object
}
```

`(params) => {code}` is a analog of `function(params){code}`. Some think that it is better.

Answer (score 2):

The code is destructuring the function parameters.

```
elements.map(({ length }) => length);
```

is same as

```
elements.map(x => x.length);
```

In the first example the code is creating a local variable to callback called `lengthFooBArX` and assign that variable to the `length` property of the element.

The first code is equivalent to.

```
elements.map(x => {
    let lengthFooBArX = x.length;
    return lengthFoBArX;
}
```

The syntax for destucturing is

```
let {length} = x;
//is same as
let length = x.length;
```

If the variable name an property name are different then

```
let {length:otherName} = x;
//is same as 
let otherName = x.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of arrow function, destructuring the strings and renaming inside the destructuring.

It's roughly equivalent to the following:

```
elements.map( function( element ) {
  var lengthFooBArX = element.length;
  return lengthFooBArX;
});
```

So the `({ length })` part extracts the length of the string. So in the first iteration, the string is 'Hydrogen', which has a length of 8 characters.

The `:lengthFooBArX` part of `elements.map(({ length :lengthFooBArX })` renames the variable we create from 'length', to the name 'lengthFooBArX'.

And finally, the arrow implicitly returns `lengthFooBArX`, as the result of mapping 'Hydrogen', so the first element in the resulting array is 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at this code 
`elements.map(({ length :lengthFooBArX }) => lengthFooBArX);`, you can see that you're applying the length function on the string passed in map function and the output is the length because that is what is enclosed in {}.

It can also be written in a syntactic sugar way like `elements.map((element) => {
  return element.length;
});`

Comment: The OP *doesn't* see, that's the whole point. And your equivalent is the *non*-syntactic sugar version.